# How to serialize Secret key in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, secret-key

I am working on a keystore implementation for an API with Spring Boot

This is my endpoint in the controller:

```
    @PostMapping(path = {"/sec-crypto/store/key"}, consumes = TYPE_JSON, produces = TYPE_JSON)
    public void storeSecretKey(@RequestBody final KeystoreSecretKeyWrapper keystoreSecretKeyWrapper) throws CertificateException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException{...}
```

The wrapper class contains a SecretKeyDTO object which looks like this

```
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class SecretKeyDTO {
    private String cryptoProvider;
    private String secretKeyAlias;
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    private char[] keyPassword;

    public SecretKeyDTO() {

    }

    // Getter & Setter
}
```

and a object ob KeyStoreRequest which looks like this

```
import java.io.InputStream;

public class KeyStoreRequest {

    public static String cryptoProvider;
    public static String keyStoreType;

    public static char[] keyStorePassword;
    public static String keyStoreName;

    public KeyStoreRequest() {
    }

    //Getter & Setter

}
```

Now if i call the API with following JSON request body

````
    {
        "keyStoreRequest": {
            "cryptoProvider" : "BC",
            "keyStoreType" : "PKCS12",
            "keyStorePassword" : "topsecret",
            "keyStoreName" : "keystore"
        },
        "secretKeyDTO" : {
            "cryptoProvider" : "BC",
            "secretKeyAlias" : "myKey",
            "secretKey" :"Zoxc7wp6iEOPdK3sgBpLn71j59Sacm+7I2uRcMuRGjtDid63IiNh7zZ/HzbRk/1lOy9uwvrYVIAxJkmNTAbw/qPRC2ZeXWy1Fw0yu/CAQn4exLTZmMV784QWLej1az4r05WeoPs55hEddCOQm+3KBKLhA/fCdVf+7HYEa5TKksAM0/6KlPZZGALOdcf6Qn6ZJM+TL8HQ71d+jyb0l7Ye92S+UnNwP3H4UW6T2QtD8rix+c019me0q3/EdtFdV2vnGhyM+L8gvkck6Cn9Yeg4mMSib8RYYCx0nRPCqx7C4cbU2QuYKT9oTHlZl/IH3osFf2oM+sRqu4aRqby2PrHm7w==",
            "keyPassword":"topsecret"
        }
    }```
    
I get a *InvalidDefinitionException*. Cannot construct instance of javax.crypto.SecretKey (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information. 
    
I saw some related questions where they put @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes for solving the issue, but i do not know if they are necessary here too and if yes, where to put them.
    
I also tried providing the complete information from key generation into the request with algorithm information, format etc. but it still did not work.

Must have to do something with the serialization of the Secretkey but i can not help how to serialize it correctly. 

Please help if possible.
````

Comment: Which implementation of the `SecretKey` interface you're using in your application?

Answer (score 0):

`javax.crypto.SecretKey` is an interface and the compiler is telling you to use an implementation of that interface.

You can see what implementations you can use here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKey.html

(you probably want an instance of `SecretKeySpec`)